# Entities vs. Services in domain driven design (DDD)

Tags: design, object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design

I wanted to get some feedback on the design of a chat application I recently developed. The application is written in PHP, but the language probably isn't important here.

The main components are `User`, `Conversation`, and `Message`:

```php
class User {
    public function getId(): int {}
    public function getUsername(): string {}
    public function getFirstName(): string {}
    public function getLastName(): string {}

    // token used with a 3rd party API for sending messages
    public function getToken(): ?string;
    
    // if a user doesn't have a token they can't be messaged
    public function isOnline(): bool {}

    public function __construct(int $id, string $username, ...) {}
}

class Conversation {
    public function getId(): int {}
    public function getUsers(): User[] {}

    public function __construct(int $id, array $users) {}
}

class Message {
    public function getId(): int {}
    public function getText(): string {}
    public function getConversation(): Conversation {}
    public function getAuthor(): User {}

    public function __construct(int $id, string $text, Conversation $conversation) {}
}
```

I also have some services:

```php
class MessageSender implements MessageSenderInterface
{
    private LoggerInterface $logger;

    public function send(Message $message): void {
        foreach ($message->getConversation()->getUsers() as $user) {
            if (!$user->isOnline()) {
                $this->logger->warn('User is offline and cannot be messaged');
            }

            if ($user->equals($message->getAuthor())) {
                // continue; don't send messages to authors
            }
            
            $messageData = [
                'to' => $user->getToken(),
                'from' => $message->getAuthor()->getUsername(),
                'text' => $message->getText(),
            ];
            // send the message through some external API
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the work is done through the `MessageSender`, but I'm wondering if the domain might be better encapsulated with something like this:

```php
class Message {
    public function getId(): int {}
    public function getText(): string {}

    public function __construct(int $id, string $text, Conversation $conversation) {}

    public function send(MessageSenderInterface $sender, LoggerInterface $logger) {
        ... send logic in here
    }
}
```

You can see that by moving the `send` functionality inside of the `Message` object we totally get rid of two exposed properties (`getConversation` and `getAuthor` are gone) and could effectively remove the service altogether. But as a result, the message object now knows about loggers and message senders, even if they are just interfaces.

What does DDD say about this? I tend to prefer exposing less data and like the encapsulation the second option provides.

Answer (score 6):

Some DDD practitioners suggest that it is ok to inject technology layers dynamically into your domain model. Modeled that way, your domain code will not be directly dependent on technology components and only talk through abstract interfaces.

But I would suggest that you keep only the domain related code in the domain model layer and organize all technology interactions (DB, Message Brokers, Loggers) in your service layer. These are typically Application Services and Command Handlers in the DDD/CQRS lingo.

Here are some reasons why placing code that interacts with technology components in the domain model is probably a bad practice:

1. You use DDD to reduce complexity, but injecting technology aspects into your domain model will obscure your vision of real business logic. It will get lost in translation when most of your code handles technology concerns like loading and persisting data or sending messages.
2. Your domain model ends up having some knowledge about workflows in your technology components. It knows when to persist data, how to persist data, and when to send messages, among other stuff.
3. You will need a different layer anyway to perform validations spanning the aggregate collection (checking for uniqueness of email address, for example).
4. Your domain cannot be tested in isolation. You are always organizing technology components (or mocks) when you test domain logic.

Mapping this thought process to your example, the logic to decide whether to send the message would be in the domain layer. The code to format the event data and dispatch to the message broker would be in the service layer.

On a separate note, one wouldn't organize these three components (User, Conversation, and Message) in this way in a DDD application. You would think about transaction boundaries and create `aggregates` around data objects.

A `User` would be an aggregate, with its own enclosed objects and behavior. A `Conversation` would be another aggregate and enclose `Message` objects within it, and all message related interactions would be via the Conversation aggregate.

Because they are separate aggregates, you would not embed `User` objects into a `Conversation` aggregate. You would only have references (user identifiers). You would have a read model that tracks which users are online in a Conversation and use it to dispatch messages.

I suggest you go through the [EventSourcery](https://eventsourcery.com) course for a good understanding of these concepts. The code for the course is actually in PHP.

---

Update 1:

Your `Message` object is reaching back to the `Conversation` object to gather users to do its work, so it makes sense to enclose it within the `Conversation` object.

I will talk about two concepts that may not be part of your architecture right now but would help: **Application Services** and **Domain Events**.

You would introduce an intermediate "Application Service" layer between your controller and the Domain Layer.

The App Service will be responsible for invoking the (injected) infrastructure services, calling the domain layer, and persisting/loading necessary data. The Controller's responsibility is only to gather the request params (gather user input in your case), ensure authentication (if needed), and then make the call to the Application Service method.

Application Services are the direct clients of the domain model and act as intermediaries to coordinate between the external world and the domain layer. They are responsible for handling infrastructure concerns like ID Generation, Transaction Management, Encryption, etc. Such responsibilities are not concerns of the Controller layer either.

Let's assume `MessageSender` is transformed into an Application Service. Here is an example control flow:

1. API sends the request with `conversation_id`, `user_id` (author), and `message`.
2. Application Service loads `Conversation` from the database. If the Conversation ID is valid, and the author can participate in this conversation (these are invariants), you invoke a `send` method on the `Conversation` object.
3. The Conversation object adds the message to its own data, runs its business logic, and decides which users to send the message.
4. The Conversation object raises `events`, to be dispatched into a message interface (these are collected in a temporary variable valid for that session) and returns. These events contain the entire data to reconstruct details of the message (timestamps, audit log, etc.), and don't just cater to what is pushed out to the receiver later.
5. The Application Service persists the updated Conversation object and dispatches all events raised during the recent processing.
6. A subscriber listening for the event gathers it, constructs the message in the right format (picking only the data it needs from the event), and performs the actual push to the receiver.

With this structure, you have a good implementation of the Open-Closed Principle.

1. Your Conversation object changes only if you are changing business logic (like who should receive the message).
2. Your Application service will seldom change because it simply loads and persists Conversation objects and publishes any raised events to the message broker.
3. Your Subscriber logic changes only if you are pushing additional data to the receiver.

---

Update 2: Pseudocode

Application Service:

```py
class MessageSender(ApplicationService):
    def send_message(request):
        // Deconstruct request object and call method
        conversation = ConversationRepo.find_by_id(request.id)

        // Call a method on the aggregate that generates events and updates the aggregates state
        conversation.send_message(request.from_user_id, request.content)

        // Application Service saves the aggregate
        ConversationRepo.save(conversation)

        // Any events raised are dispatched once the conversation has been successfully saved
        for event in conversation.events:
            message_interface.dispatch(event)
```

Domain Model:

```py
class User(Aggregate):
    id: int
    username: str
    first_name: str
    last_name: str

    token: str
    is_online: bool

class Message(Entity):
    id: int
    author_id: int
    content: str
    sent_at: time

class Conversation(Aggregate):
    id: int
    users: list
    messages = list

    events = list // not persisted

    def send_message(from_user_id, content):
        for user in self.users:
            if not user.is_online:
                logger.warn("User is offline and cannot be messaged")
            
            if user.id == from_user_id:
                // continue; do not send messages to authors

            messages.append(Message(author_id=from_user_id, content=content, sent_at=datetime.utcnow()))
            self.events.add(SendMessageEvent(to=user.token, from=user.username, text=content))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Curious if you could talk a little bit more about sending messages from a `Conversation`. I hadn't considered that, but I'm curious how you'd avoid not injecting technology layers there, too.

Comment: I updated the answer with additional details. You can implement it in phases, modify to take advantage of existing infrastructure, or compromise on intermediate steps, but the walkthrough represents ideal flow. Do ask if you need more clarity.

Comment: This is great thank you!  Would the `Conversation` take an event dispatcher to raise a `MessageSentEvent` that could be consumed by something that can handle actually doing the sending. Is that right? Or maybe you're saying we'd need a function like this: `Conversation::send(string $message, User $sender): SendMessageEvent[]`. My only issue with this second option is that I worry about leaking this to the application service. You might imagine we want to persist these send events to a database and if they should be part of a `Conversation` then I'm not sure we should expose this to a service.

Comment: I would separate the creation of events from the process of dispatching the events. Your aggregates should create the domain events while their perform their business logic and keep a list of these events. The application layer can than access these events from the aggregate object and make sure the events are dispatched to their subscribers. This will also ease unit testing of the domain model as you only have to make sure the list of expected events could be found rather than injecting some dispatcher or having the unit test subscribe to domain events which makes everything harder to test.

Comment: @afh's comment is  on target. I have updated the answer with some pseudocode to help you visualize it. It's just pseudocode though; please tweak as required for your language.

Comment: I have shown `users` to be full-blown objects in `conversation` aggregate, to make it easier to understand. In reality, you would only include the user IDs taking part in the conversation. Also, the user's `online` state is probably stored in another data structure (apart from `user` and conversation`).

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking (and this is true outside of DDD), you want to arrange dependencies so that code depends on things that are more stable then itself. Here stable means something that changes comparatively less often as the software evolves. (Initially, you'll have to go with an educated guess based on your understanding of the domain, but over time, as you work on the system, you can get a better sense of what tends to be stable, provided that you're looking).

So, while it's true that entities should generally encapsulate business logic, some of the objects in your domain will be better represented as simple data structures (so, just collections of fields, very little behavior - more or less what you have now). These objects will be those that don't have particularly interesting behavioral interactions with some other set of objects. E.g., they will not be members of (non trivial) aggregates that encapsulate important business rules; instead, they will mostly be manipulated or used by other code as data. That said, as the codebase evolves, if you actively seek opportunities to refactor and restructure parts of it, you may see more behavior rich objects emerge.

But for now, the concept of a message seems like a pretty stable thing. If that's the case, I'd rather have things depend on it, then vice versa. And, you're right, it feels wrong for the message, as conceptualized right now, to know about loggers and external message sending services.

I want to direct your attention to something else, though. Take a look at your `MessageSender` class, and its `send` method. There's some proper domain logic in it - it encapsulates rules that determine when a message can be sent, to whom, etc. But then it jumps to a different level of abstraction, transforming data into a format suitable for an external API to consume:

```php
    class MessageSender implements MessageSenderInterface
    {
        private LoggerInterface $logger;
    
        public function send(Message $message): void {

            //////// --- this is domain logic --- ///////////////////////////
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            foreach ($message->getConversation()->getUsers() as $user) {
                if (!$user->isOnline()) {
                    $this->logger->warn('User is offline and cannot be messaged');
                }
    
                if ($user->equals($message->getAuthor())) {
                    // continue; don't send messages to authors
                }

                //////// --- this is infrastructure --- ////////////////////                
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                $messageData = [
                    'to' => $user->getToken(),
                    'from' => $message->getAuthor()->getUsername(),
                    'text' => $message->getText(),
                ];
                // send the message through some external API
            }
        }
    }
```

IMO, the more pertinent refactoring is to separate out the infrastructure-related (lower-level) parts (check your code for other places where this can be done). It would end up looking something like this:

```php
    // Note that this class doesn't implement the interface now. It doesn't need to.
    // Instead, it has a reference to a MessageServiceInterface instance.
    class MessageSender   
    {
        // these could be injected
        private LoggerInterface $logger;
        private MessageServiceInterface $messageService;   // <---
    
        public function send(Message $message): void {
            foreach ($message->getConversation()->getUsers() as $user) {
    
                if (!$user->isOnline()) {
                    $this->logger->warn('User is offline and cannot be messaged');
                    continue;
                }
    
                if ($user->equals($message->getAuthor())) {
                    continue;  // don't send messages to authors
                }

                $this->messageService->sendTo($user, $message);
            }
        }

        // other methods...
    }
```

Now it doesn't mix levels of abstraction, and when you read the code, it actually more closely expresses the business logic, without the extra clutter that was related to the logistics of sending the message (the logging messes up things a bit, but still). It's also separates responsibilities more clearly: this class handles the higher level business logic, while the `$messageService` object handles calling the external API (and associated data conversion). More importantly, the separation of responsibilities now means that there's a clear interface between the two components. In other parts of your codebase, the two aspects of the code may be more intermingled, implicitly coupled to each other in non-obvious ways - and if you leave them like that, they are only going to get more coupled over time.

This also enables proper dependency inversion - the `MessageSender` declares that it relies on an abstraction, the `MessageServiceInterface` (this interface should be in the same layer as `MessageSender`), and then a class in the infrastructure layer implements this interface, providing the actual message-sending capabilities.

Going back to your domain entities now, there are probably some things you can do to enrich them with behavior - and to make your code more expressive and readable. For example, in `MessageSender`, you're checking to see if the current user is the message author or not. That seems like a rule that can be expected to remain relatively stable. One thing you could do here is to enable either `Message` or `Conversation` to give you a list of users with the author excluded:

```php
    foreach ($message->getConversation()->getUsers() as $user) {
        //...

        if ($user->equals($message->getAuthor())) {
            continue;  // don't send messages to authors
        }

        //...
    }

    // ----- vs --------------------------------

    foreach ($message->getRecipients() as $recipient) {
        //...
    }
```

You'll probably be able to find more opportunities like this, but don't go overboard - since *other things* depend on these entities, try to refactor them in a way that doesn't significantly impact their stability. If you introduce a method like this, and it has to be modified on nearly every change (resulting in cascading changes), than that method is not useful, design-wise; that code belongs somewhere else, where the impact of changes can be contained.

DDD being all about discovering domain concepts and reexamining your assumptions, you can explore this further. It's possible that the previous arrangement is not quite right. Should a message know who its recipients are? What if you want to forward it to different conversation? Furthermore, maybe your `MessageSender` is better described as something like a `MessageBoard`. Maybe the message board maintains a list of participants (what you currently call `Conversation`), and the message itself does not. Maybe the code from the previous example could be written like this:

```php
    // in MessageBoard.send($message)

    $recipients = $this->participants->getRecipientsFor($message);
    foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
        //...
    }
```

So now you've transformed a fairly generic idea of a "message sender" into an actual domain concept - it's now an explicit domain object, and a non-anemic one, too. Maybe that makes more sense, maybe not.
I'm not saying this is the way to go, I'm just trying to give you some ideas, to help you think out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

> I tend to prefer exposing less data and like the encapsulation the second option provides.

Excellent. That is the way to go.

Now, is it a problem that "domain objects" know about "technology"? Of course not. Let's look at this way:

The people who tell you it's ok to have data structures and that "business logic" needs to be "pure" and "clean", also will tell you to *expose tehnology* in your application as public classes and methods. So your application now has a lot of technology-related stuff that knows your business and some data structures with "pure" logic, which have to be "synchronized" to backends somehow.

The alternative is to have real objects with real methods that model the business. The application is now *only* about the business, with "technology" only existing in the implementation of said business-related methods, i.e. hidden.

As our job as developers is to deliver functionality not technology, the second approach seems closer to what we actually want.

Also, here are my counterarguments to some points raised in other posts:

1. Using technology will obscure the business things: **The contrary is true**. Having *visible technology components* will obscure the business. Having technology in the *implementation* of a method does not obscure anything. Visible parts are the classes and public methods. Those need to be technology-free.
2. Your domain will have to know when to save data and when to send messages. **Well, who else?** Who knows when to save some data or communicate with some third party system if not the implementation of a business logic?
3. You will need a different layer anyway to perform validations spanning the aggregate collection (checking for uniqueness of email address, for example). **No, you don't.** You don't need that if your methods are business-relevant.
4. Your domain cannot be tested in isolation. **FUD**.

Comment: This question is about Domain Driven Design. There are books and online resources available. You might not like this approach or do things differently and it may even be better in some cases, but it’s no longer called Domain Driven Design.

Comment: @RikD I don't know what you mean. Both rich (what I describe above) and anemic (what you seem to be referring to) style of DDD exists in the literature. Even if it didn't, I don't see why your assessment of what constitutes DDD is any more valid than mine.

Comment: I’m not talking about rich vs anemic. DDD models should be rich, I think we’re both on the same page for that. Your answer seems to suggest putting logging, persistence and other infrastructure concerns *inside* the domain. I don’t think that’s suggested anywhere in the DDD literature.

Comment: That's interesting. I've read the Blue Book, and came away with the impression that the Domain Model is the interface for everything business-related. Including persisting, logging or whatever it needs to do to achieve the business case I've initiated. If not, what's the point? How can it be "rich" in any sense of the word when it can't even log or persist?